# В чем ошибка при удалении элемента списка из адаптера?

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

Получаю во время удаления элемента списка такую ошибку:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

если я правильно понял документацию и источники с которыми я ознакомился, то эта ошибка означает что я передал для удаления либо очень большой индекс либо очень маленький. Но так получается, что иногда элемент удаляется нормально и все происходит правильно. Вот на какие строки мне указывает эта ошибка:

```
mNames.remove(adapterPosition);
```

в методе:

```
public static void deleteAttachment(int adapterPosition) {
mNames.remove(adapterPosition);
adapter.updateNames(mNames);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

этот метод находится в активити где размещен список с адаптером. Вот вторая строка:

```
WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(position);
```

эта строка находится в слушателе нажатия для удаления в адаптере:

```
 holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (draft_files) {
                    MySingleton.getInstance().setContext(context);
                    MySingleton.getInstance().deleteFLDraft(MySingleton.getInstance().getDraft_id(), mNames.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
                    WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(position);
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", "delete file from draft");
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

я не могу понять как исправить и почему у меня иногда получается удалить этот элемент нормально.

Comment: Перед вызови метода удаления делайте проверку того, что adapterPosition находится в пределах mNames

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, та можно и проверку сделать но как-то странно что нужно ее делать, ведь иногда все работает так как нужно

Comment: Окно и адаптеры в Android постоянно пересоздаются при повороте например, или при переходе на них, поэтому там могут быть в какой-то момент пустые адаптеры и индексы равные -1. Можете вывести и удостовериться

Comment: ну на данный момент я закинул все в логи, и получается что я передаю в функцию значение 1 а размер массива у меня 0, и получается что я хочу удалить первый элемент из общего кол-ва 0

Comment: А mNames-то у вас что из себя представляет? Где и чем он инициализируется?

Comment: в текущей ситуации я его получаю из интента, и если бы он был пустым то у меня ничего в списке не было

Comment: Значит в какой-то момент он пуст  и надо все-таки проверять индекс

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87023/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-alexander-chernin).